# NSMakeRange causes app to lock up; slow performance

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsstring, nsrange

I have a dilemna that I thought I was solving pretty good so far. However, when I test it with a UITableView I get all kinds of warnings such as:

```
[__NSCFString substringWithRange:]: Range {2147483647, 2147483701} out of bounds; string length 56. This will become an exception for apps linked after 10.9. Warning shown once per app execution.
```

I will describe what I'm trying to do before I post my method below. Basically, when a user uploads a profile photo, I set a unique substring after their username, but before the file extension (.png) Example: a username of JohnDoe takes a new profile photo, I set the file name to be:

```
NSString *file = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"JohnDoe%@.png",[[NSProcessInfo processInfo] globallyUniqueString]];
```

I do this so the app can tell later if it needs to download a user's friend's new profile picture, based on seeing if this complete NSString is saved to disk locally, if I can't find it saved locally, I simply download it from the web. The problem is most likely coming from the UITableView calling the method continuously.

Also, this needs to be done on the client side, so please don't discuss backend related solutions.

This is the method I came up with to get the actual unique NSString of the user's profile image file name. This method of mine is called in the: `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method

```
- (NSString *)actualPhotoPath:(NSDictionary *)input
{
    // This code needs work, ridiculous bottle neck!
    NSRange r1 = [[input objectForKey:@"pic"] rangeOfString:[input objectForKey:@"username"]];
    NSRange r2 = [[input objectForKey:@"pic"] rangeOfString:@".png"];
    NSRange rSub = NSMakeRange(r1.location + r1.length, r2.location - r1.location - r1.length);
    // Hangs up on the below line of code eventually
    NSString *sub = [[input objectForKey:@"pic"] substringWithRange:rSub];
    NSString *actual = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@.png",[input objectForKey:@"username"],sub];
    NSLog(@"%@",actual);
    return actual;
}
```

I appreciate any help offered! Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should check `if(r1.location != NSNotFound)` and `if(r2.location != NSNotFound)`

2147483647<sub>10</sub> == 0x7FFFFFFF<sub>16</sub> equals 2<sup>31</sup>-1, it is the highest NSInteger value on a 32-bit system, also named `NSIntegerMax`.

A look at the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html):

> ```
> enum {
>    NSNotFound = NSIntegerMax
> };
> ```

---

```
- (NSString *)actualPhotoPath:(NSDictionary *)input
{
    NSRange r1 = [[input objectForKey:@"pic"] rangeOfString:[input objectForKey:@"username"]];
    NSRange r2 = [[input objectForKey:@"pic"] rangeOfString:@".png"];

    if(r1.location != NSNotFound && r2.location != NSNotFound){
        NSRange rSub = NSMakeRange(r1.location + r1.length, r2.location - r1.location - r1.length);
    
        NSString *sub = [[input objectForKey:@"pic"] substringWithRange:rSub];
        NSString *actual = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@.png",[input objectForKey:@"username"],sub];
        NSLog(@"%@",actual);
        return actual;
    }

    // if the code reaches this block, one of the ranges didn't work.
    // do what ever must be done in that case here
    return nil;
}
```

---

Actually you should first create `r1`, and if location != NSFound you should use the location for r2 to make sure that a string png is found after it.

```
- (NSString *)actualPhotoPath:(NSDictionary *)input
{
    NSRange r1 = [[input objectForKey:@"pic"] rangeOfString:[input objectForKey:@"username"]];
    if (r1.location != NSNotFound ) {
        NSRange r2 = [[[input objectForKey:@"pic"] substringFromIndex:r1.location] rangeOfString:@".png"];
        
        if(r2.location != NSNotFound){
            NSRange rSub = NSMakeRange(r1.location + r1.length, r2.location - r1.location - r1.length);
            
            NSString *sub = [[input objectForKey:@"pic"] substringWithRange:rSub];
            NSString *actual = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@.png",[input objectForKey:@"username"],sub];
            NSLog(@"%@",actual);
            return actual;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
```

---

Alternatively you could use NSRegularExpressions or NSScanner.

Comment: 2147483647 is 0x7FFFFFFF which is `NSNotFound` on 32-bit systems. Always check for errors! Sure the "happy path" is more fun but damn, the errors can kill! Gotta handle the "unhappy path" too.

Comment: Coincidentally (or perhaps not), this value is also the maximum length for an `NSString` object.

Comment: ~ 2.2 billion letters should be enough for most texts.

Comment: How could I implement this?

Comment: Simply check the range: `if (r1.location == NSNotFound) { //handle unhappy path }`.

Comment: enclose the line where you create the new range rSub with a check, if both ranges' locations aren't NSNotFound.

Comment: Like this? `if (r1.location != NSNotFound && r2.location != NSNotFound)
    {
        rSub = NSMakeRange(r1.location + r1.length, r2.location - r1.location - r1.length);
    }`

Comment: Yes. Also insure that `r2.location - r1.location - r1.length > 0`.

Comment: Please elaborate Zaph

Comment: Make sure the length is > 0.

Comment: If you need more than 2.2Bn characters, you have to get an iPhone 5 or iPad Air with the 64-bit processor, where NSIntegerMax is much larger.  ;)

Comment: Doubt that 1 64-bit processor will allow more characters. Hey, Apple can't even handle UTF plane 1 characters properly. It was a little funky with surrogate airs but complete ridiculous for emoji, one emoji character returns a length of 2? Really, that was a good idea?

Comment: Wait, my unique string that I save upon uploading the photo is between the username and .png

Comment: I don't think this is going to work for me, I'm getting it to return nil for some reason, which can't happen for my use case.

Comment: no, this is right: your string isn't there, or the object you are searching on is nil.

Comment: Zaph just want's things not to crash. So one needs to pre-check or insure, like on division that the divisor is not 0.

Comment: The object can't be nil, all my file names are guaranteed to be: UserNameHereUnique.png

Comment: Well, you present a case where the code can't crash. Yet the computer disagrees and it has the last say. Trace through with the debugger, watch all the values, find the problem.

Comment: is this `[input objectForKey:@"pic"]` nil?

Comment: Here is what I found at the else statement: `2014-05-31 22:22:40.028 test[47352:60b] r1 length 0
2014-05-31 22:22:40.028 test[47352:60b] r2 length 4
2014-05-31 22:22:40.028 test[47352:60b] r1 location 2147483647
2014-05-31 22:22:40.028 test[47352:60b] r2 location 54
2014-05-31 22:22:40.029 test[47352:60b] crap!`

Comment: I wrote this sample program: https://gist.github.com/vikingosegundo/417bac2c3b5544be81c8 works for me.

Comment: at the beginning of `actualPhotoPath:`, log `input`. what does it say?

Comment: It looks like this is a serious issue: `pic: https://s3.amazonaws.com/test.com/Maria245D.png
username: Asb24
r1 length: 0
r2 length: 4
r1 location: 2147483647
r2 location: 52
crap!`  Obviously, the username is not the same as the input. I'm thinking this has to do with the UITableView calling the method very fast, and therefore the next dictionary is applied for some reason before the method returns?

Comment: hm, no. that is unlikely. you should ask a new question with the code where you create the dictionary.

Comment: I don't think I need to ask a new question, there is nothing wrong with my dictionary.

Comment: The revised answer now returns null for objects that didnt with the original answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54858/discussion-between-troop231-and-vikingosegundo).

Comment: No. it is 5 am in the morning here, and I have spent one hour on this. I have answered your original question. That your data doesn't fit to neither your question nor the answers is something you need to investigate.

Comment: Honestly don't care that its 5am or 3pm, I wasnt seeking an immediate answer. Not the end of world.

Answer (score 0):

You should check that your ranges are valid in unsigned territory.  For instance, if you do:

`NSString* s = [@"foo" substringWithRange: {NSNotFound, 0}];`

You'll get the same kind of exception.

Additionally, if you haven't already, you add a Breakpoint for all Exceptions in Xcode, you can inspect where this is happening in your code.

Comment: Yes, always add an Exception breakpoint–unless you are using Core Data, it uses exceptions in the "happy path"–ugh!